# grep lookbehind with anchor unexpected results

Tags: grep, gnu

Why doesn't this anchored lookbehinnd assertion work as expected?

```
$ grep -Po '^(?<=field_one: ).*' <<< "field_one: 123" # no match. non-zero exit. why?

$ grep -Po '(?<=field_one: ).*' <<< "field_one: 123"  # match, no anchor
123
$ grep -Po '(?<=^field_one: ).*' <<< "field_one: 123" # match, anchor inside lookbehind
123
$ grep -Po '^(field_one: ).*' <<< "field_one: 123"    # match, no lookbehind
field_one: 123
```

grep version: grep (GNU grep) 3.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't expect `^(?<=field_one: ).*` to match any string because `^` matches the start of string position, and then `(?<=field_one: )` [*positive lookbehind*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) requires the `field_one:`  immediately *to the left* of the current location. The lookbehind pattern is only checked at the start of the string. There is and can be NO text before the string beginning and this is a kind of a regex that will never match any string.

Use

```
grep -Po '(?<=^field_one: ).*' <<< "field_one: 123"
```

With the `^` inside the lookbehind as `^` will be part of the lookaround check and will be tested at each position, and if it finds a location that is immediately preceded with `field_one:`  at the start of the string, a match will be returned.

Another alternative:

```
grep -Po '^field_one:\s*\K.*' <<< "field_one: 123"
                     ^^^^^
```

Here, no lookbehind is used, the `^field_one:\s*` pattern matches `field_one:` at the start of the string, then 0+ whitespaces are consumed and the [`\K` operator](https://www.regular-expressions.info/keep.html) discards all the text matched so far. Only the text that is further matched with `.*` will be returned.

See [online `grep` demo](https://ideone.com/R2EzsE).